# Testing expandable Elements with Fitnesse

Tags: testing, fitnesse

In my Fitnessse tests I've got many elements which are supposed to expand. 
When I let them expand individually, it works. But when I want to expand a few objects more, the former elements shut automatically. And I don't know why.
Can anyone help? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post more information - an example of what you tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @Mike Stockdale Say I've got a survey with several questions and a Yes/No Radio Button for each question. And everytime the user clicks on Yes, a follow-up question appears. You can expand all follow-up questions by hand, but when I try to implement this state by an automatic Fitnesse Test, former questions, which are already answered with Yes, turn into No on their own. I hope my description was fairly comprehensible. If not, I'll give it another try.

Comment: Can you post an example of a FitNesse test that is doing this?